# Xcode 10: Code Signing my App+Framework fails, because of failure signing 3rd party dependency framework (PromiseKit). Works in Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, code-signing, xcode10

I have an Xcode 10 - iOS12 swift project that links against My own framework (also Xcode 10 + iOS12).

The app project is referencing my framework project as a sub-project reference.

My Framework project references PromiseKit.framework (a universal framework - fat library), made using the following build script:

```
# Merge Script

# 1
# Set bash script to exit immediately if any commands fail.
set -e

# 2
# Setup some constants for use later on.
FRAMEWORK_NAME="PromiseKit"

# 3
# If remnants from a previous build exist, delete them.
if [ -d "${SRCROOT}/build" ]; then
rm -rf "${SRCROOT}/build"
fi

# 4
# Build the framework for device and for simulator (using
# all needed architectures).
xcodebuild -target "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration Release -arch arm64 only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphoneos"
xcodebuild -target "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -configuration Release -arch x86_64 only_active_arch=no defines_module=yes -sdk "iphonesimulator"

# 5
# Remove .framework file if exists on Desktop from previous run.
if [ -d "${SRCROOT}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" ]; then
rm -rf "${SRCROOT}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
fi

# 6
# Copy the device version of framework to Desktop.
cp -r "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" "${SRCROOT}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

# 7
# Replace the framework executable within the framework with
# a new version created by merging the device and simulator
# frameworks' executables with lipo.
lipo -create -output "${SRCROOT}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# 8
# Copy the Swift module mappings for the simulator into the
# framework.  The device mappings already exist from step 6.
cp -r "${SRCROOT}/build/Release-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" "${SRCROOT}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule"

# 9
# Delete the most recent build.
if [ -d "${SRCROOT}/build" ]; then
rm -rf "${SRCROOT}/build"
fi
```

When I go to archive my Parent App Project using Xcode 10 (And also 9.4.1) with Bitcode ON (that contains My Framework reference, and PromiseKit Fat library), I get the following error on the Signing stage: (Failed to verify bitcode in PromiseKit.framework/PromiseKit: error Cannot extract bundle from /var/folders..../(x86_64)   - which suggests that it's simulator slice related)
[image]

If I turn the "Rebuild from Bitcode" option in the Organizer to OFF, then I get a different error: (Code signing "PromiseKit.framework" failed)
[image]

However, if I use Xcode 9.4.1 With Bitcode OFF, then it exports and signs fine.

Why is it trying to individually re-sign sub frameworks, and what can I do to alleviate the issues?   I need the archiving to work normally with Xcode 10, along with any future third party dependencies being added to my framework target.  (This is the first dynamic framework dependency added to my Framework target.  Before I was "baking in" - in-boarding all 3rd parties for ease of development purposes, but PromiseKit is difficult to inboard due to extensive dependencies on Objective-c).

The Xcode Archive log is:

```
 {
        code = 330;
        description = "Failed to resolve linkage dependency PromiseKit x86_64 -> @rpath/libswiftFoundation.dylib: Unknown arch x86_64";
        info =             {
        };
        level = WARN;
    },
            {
        code = 330;
        description = "Failed to resolve linkage dependency PromiseKit x86_64 -> @rpath/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: Unknown arch x86_64";
        info =             {
        };
        level = WARN;
    },
            {
        code = 0;
        description = "Failed to verify bitcode in PromiseKit.framework/PromiseKit:\nerror: Cannot extract bundle from /var/folders/q5/hm9v_6x53lj0gj02yxqtkmd40000gn/T/IDEDistributionOptionThinning.RJD/Payload/MyAppName.app/Frameworks/PromiseKit.framework/PromiseKit (x86_64)\n\n";
        info =             {
        };
        level = ERROR;
        type = "malformed-payload";
    }
);
```

Some other solutions I tried was using a Project Reference to PromiseKit, instead of a Framework reference, however this doesn't work - in that I still need a framework reference from my main project, because I will get "library not loaded" error at runtime, if running without a FW reference. Same issue occurs when archiving while using a project reference.

Comment: An update:  I noticed that in my Interface builder designer, I was getting an error on the top:  "Image missing: PromiseKit.framework..."  So this Framework-In-Framework reference is causing all sorts of issues for us right now.  I am trying to "Bake-In" promise kit, by compiling it into my Framework as source files (as I do with other light weight third party frameworks).  Cocoapods does not support Framework targets.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try this! It worked for me and many other people:

Goto

Build phases > Add > New Run Script Phase

The code should work for any default shell, but I recommend just using **/bin/sh**

and include the following code:

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
# skip if we run in debug
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]; then
echo "Skip frameworks cleaning in debug version"
exit 0
fi

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

It seems hat some frameworks ship architectures, that will not be used in the application.
Xcode will refuse to sign them. The above script removes unused architectures.

Credits: Some guy at GitHub, I can't find the exact source anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This was the last frustrating thing I was dealing with before distribution and your comment saved me from a bunch of unnecessary searching.

Comment: The random Github guy needs some props!  This is excellent and working with Xcode 10.3.

Comment: Now why did this break when I upgraded to xcode 10.3? Maybe it was rather the conversion from swift 3 to swift 4? Either way, this fixed the signing error(s).

Comment: After reading tons of posts and try everything, this solved my problem. My framework is compiled by an external provider and seems like it delivered the framework with more than one architecture. Thank you!!

Comment: @YoshiJaeger is there change required in above code according to my Project

Comment: I did this, but I still got an error, so I had to make some changes instead of this "*.framework" I used this "FRAMEWORK_NAME*.framework" and it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here. The only workaround I've found is to use static library instead of framework.

In case you are not able to use static library, you'd better file a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me,
I have application and 2 in-house built frameworks, say **A $ B.**

Application needs A, but A needs B and since Apple doesn't recommend nesting frameworks, so both A and B had to be included in the app.

This is what my Xcode project looks like.

[image: structure of the application in Xcode]

**SOLUTION**

In the application, under **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content**, select **Embed & Sign** for all necessary frameworks. (as shown below)

[image: application frameworks]

But for all the custom framework projects, under **Frameworks and Libraries** section, select **Do Not Embed**. (as shown below)
This fixed the issue for me

[image: custom frameworks]